# Check if any installed app can open a given url

Tags: java, android, android-webview

There is a way to check if the user has any app that can open an url; like Firefox in Android does.

I would like to put a screenshot here.

A better explanation:
I have an url like in the picture. I want to search in all the activities from all apps if any has a data tag with the host from the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this page about using the PackageManager to query the system for apps that can handle a type of content and show an app chooser.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Comment: It works but also doesn't work. Why? Because I am getting all the web browsers and I don't want that.

Comment: Yeah, you can either try to find something more unique to query with or loop through the ResolveInfo objects looking for the app you want (by looking at  resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName) and only send that one to the Chooser intent.